# Custom Exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, stl, exception, multiple-inheritance

I've been trying to make some custom exception classes for a C++ library I'm working on. These custom exceptions capture extra info, such as file,line number,etc, needed for debugging, if for some reason while testing an exception is not caught in the right place. However most people seem to recommend inheriting from the std::exception class in the STL, which I agree with, but I was wondering maybe it would be better to use multiple inheritance to inherit from each of the [derived std::exception classes](http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/~tjuerges/ALMA/STL/html/classstd_1_1exception.html) (eg. std::runtime_error) and a custom exception class, as in the code below?

Another thing, how does one go about copy constructors and assignment operators in exception classes? Should they be disabled?

```
class Exception{
    public:
        explicit Exception(const char *origin, const char *file, 
                           const int line, const char *reason="", 
                           const int errno=0) throw();

        virtual ~Exception() throw();

        virtual const char* PrintException(void) throw();

        virtual int GetErrno(void);

    protected:
        std::string m_origin;
        std::string m_file;
        int m_line;
        std::string m_reason;
        int m_errno;
}; 

class RuntimeError: public virtual std::runtime_error, public Exception{
    public:
              explicit RuntimeError(const char *origin, const char *file, 
                                    const int line, const char *reason="", 
                                    const int errno=0) throw();
        virtual ~RuntimeError() throw();
};
```

Comment: What would you gain from this? Why not use single inheritance? Why do you need to customize *both* Exception and RuntimeError exceptions?

Comment: I wanted to use the functionality from my custom Exception class and maintain the STL exception hierarchy by inheriting from the various derived std::exception classes. This way a catch with:

try{
  throw RunTimeException(...);
}catch(std::runtime_error &e){
  ...
}catch(std::exception &e){...}

would also catch my custom class.
It could be a waste of time though. I could also just 

try{
  throw RunTimeException(...);
}catch(std::exception &e){...}

but it could make it harder to identify the exception then. I don't know what the typical practice is when custom exception classes?

Comment: I would say just inherit from std::runtime_error (or std::exception). If you want a specific treatment, you can have multiple catchs after all.

Comment: [as @fmuecke points out creating a custom exception class that has the features you describe (adding arbitrary data to the exception) is difficult to get correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1605799/52074) (especially in C++). easier to use code like `boost::exception` which is extensively peer-reviewed AND battle-tested.

Answer (score 17):

> I was wondering maybe it would be better to use multiple inheritance to inherit from each of the derived std::exception classes

Note that this is a problem, due to the fact that the exceptions in the standard library derive non-virtually from each other. If you introduce multiple inheritance, you get the dreaded diamond exception hierarchy without virtual inheritance and won't be able to catch derived exceptions by `std::exception&`, since your derived exception class carries two subobjects of `std::exception`, making `std::exception` an "ambiguous base class".

Concrete example:

```
class my_exception : virtual public std::exception {
  // ...
};

class my_runtime_error : virtual public my_exception
                       , virtual public std::runtime_error {
  // ...
};
```

Now `my_runtime_error` derives (indirectly) from `std::exception` twice, once through `std::run_time_error` and once through `my_exception`. Since the former doesn't derive from `std::exception` virtually, this

```
try {
  throw my_runtime_error(/*...*/);
} catch( const std::exception& x) {
  // ...
}
```

won't work.

*Edit:*

I think I've seen the first example of an exceptions class hierarchy involving MI in one of Stroustrup's books, so I concluded that, in general, it is a good idea. That the std lib's exceptions do not derive virtually from each other I consider as a failure.

When I last designed an exception hierarchy, I used MI very extensively, but did not derive from the std lib's exception classes. In that hierarchy, there were abstract exception classes which you defined so your users could catch them, and corresponding implementation classes, derived from these abstract classes and from an implementation base class, which you would actually throw. To make this easier, I defined some templates which would do all the hard work:

```
// something.h
class some_class {
private:
  DEFINE_TAG(my_error1); // these basically define empty structs that are needed to 
  DEFINE_TAG(my_error2); // distinguish otherwise identical instances of the exception 
  DEFINE_TAG(my_error3); // templates from each other (see below)
public:
  typedef exc_interface<my_error1>  exc_my_error1;
  typedef exc_interface<my_error2>  exc_my_error2;
  typedef exc_interface<my_error3,my_error2> // derives from the latter
                                    exc_my_error3;

  some_class(int i);
  // ...
};

//something.cpp
namespace {
  typedef exc_impl<exc_my_error1> exc_impl_my_error1;
  typedef exc_impl<exc_my_error2> exc_impl_my_error2;
  typedef exc_impl<exc_my_error3> exc_impl_my_error3;
  typedef exc_impl<exc_my_error1,exc_my_error2> // implements both
                                  exc_impl_my_error12;
}
some_class::some_class(int i)
{
  if(i < 0) 
    throw exc_impl_my_error3( EXC_INFO  // passes '__FILE__', '__LINE__' etc.
                            , /* ... */ // more info on error
                            ); 
}
```

Looking back at this now, I think I could have made that `exc_impl` class template derive from `std::exception` (or any other class in the std lib exception hierarchy, passed as optional template parameter), since it never derives from any other `exc_impl` instance. But back then this wasn't needed, so it never occurred to me.

Comment: Thanks for the post sbi. Would making exception classes with multiple inheritance be a good practice? Or is it better just to inherit from std::exception class?

Comment: But he does not have that problem. You have gone off on an irrelavant tangent to the problem.

Comment: @Martin: I'm not sure what you're getting at. I even quoted the question I answered to on top of my answer. And the edited part was added due to a question from Tom in his comment.

Answer (score 12):

You should try [boost::exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html)

> The purpose of Boost Exception is to
>   ease the design of exception class
>   hierarchies and to help write
>   exception handling and error reporting
>   code.
>
> It supports transporting of arbitrary
>   data to the catch site, which is
>   otherwise tricky due to the no-throw
>   requirements (15.5.1) for exception
>   types. Data can be added to any
>   exception object, either directly in
>   the throw-expression (15.1), or at a
>   later time as the exception object
>   propagates up the call stack.
>
> The ability to add data to exception
>   objects after they have been passed to
>   throw is important, because often some
>   of the information needed to handle an
>   exception is unavailable in the
>   context where the failure is detected.
>
> Boost Exception also supports
>   N2179-style copying of exception
>   objects, implemented non-intrusively
>   and automatically by the
>   boost::throw_exception function.

Comment: I've never used boost before. I'll look into it. Thanks for the post.