# Custom exception hierarchy. Dreaded diamond from std::exception and std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I Have a problem with inheritance in my own exception hierarchy.

The class `Exception` has very good functionality (backtrace, logging, ...), so it is my base class for any exception. It inherits from `std::exception` as I see suggested in many webpages. Also, I'm using a unit test framework that reports any `std::exception` being throw unexpectedly. But in a final word, it is just for convenience.

Then, I have a new `OutOfMemoryException` class which will be throw by a custom new_handler. This class inherits from `Exception`, but also inherit from `std::bad_alloc` for compatibility with existent code. This is more important I guess, since `new` will not throw `std::bad_alloc` anymore.

The problem here is obvious: since `std::bad_alloc` derive from `std::exception`, I have a *dreaded diamond situation*.

```cpp
class Exception : public std::exception { };
class OutOfMemoryException : public Exception, public std::bad_alloc { };
```

Sadly, as you can see here [stackoverflow.com...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1605852/2484624) standard exceptions do not virtual inheritance, so `std::exception` is an ambiguous base class.

Then:

1. Is it possible to solve this in any way? (I don't know, any class or template trick)
2. If it is not, is preferable that `Exception` does **not** inherit from `std::exception` or `OutOfMemoryException` does **not** from `std::bad_alloc`

I could hack the unit test framework due its permissive licence.

Thank you in advance and sorry, I am not a very good english speaker.

Comment: FWIW your class doesn't use virtual inheritance either

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes My class doesn't use it because any combination of virtual inheritance never worked for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that comes to mind is that you could use the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to make `Exception` derive from `bad_alloc` when inherited from `OutOfMemoryException` (and other exception classes you might have from other errors, e.g. RuntimeException`from`runtime_error`):

```
template<typename Base=std::exception>
class Exception: public Base {...};
class OutOfMemoryException: public Exception<std::bad_alloc> {...};
class RuntimeException: public Exception<std::runtime_error> {...};
```

Of course this means that `Exception` needs to be a template, leading to compile time overhead and problems if you actually want to catch `Exception` instead of `std::exception` to get access to its functionality (since you need to now which exception is actually thrown, which is less then optimal). This can be migrated by having another Baseclass which doesn't derive from `std::exception` and contains the real functionality:

```
class ExceptionBase {...};
template<typename Base=std::exception>
class Exception: public Base, public ExceptionBase {...};
class OutOfMemoryException: public Exception<std::bad_alloc> {...};
class RuntimeException: public Exception<std::runtime_error> {...};
```

This is  really not a great solution due to loosing some polymorphic properties and getting complex easily when you have more then one level of inheritance, but it could at least work.

Another slightly more complex solution in terms of implementation is to refactor the whole thing into two different inheritance chains with dummy classes to combine the two chains:

```
class ExceptionT {};
class OutOfMemoryT: public ExceptionT {};
class Exception:   public ExceptionT, public std::exception {};
class OutOfMemory: public OutOfMemoryT, public std::bad_alloc {};
```

This way you would throw `OutOfMemory` and catch `OutOfMemoryT` or `std::bad_alloc`.

Both of these approach make casting from one Exceptionchain (`Exception/std::exception`) to the other in the handler harder, but I would assume that that might not be that important (since `std::exception` doesn't offer much functionality besides being standard you would probably always prefer to catch Exception).

Comment: +1. The first solution should be sufficient; it does not lose any polymorphism. `OutOfMemoryException` should not inherit from `Exception<…>` though; `Exception` specializations should not be inherited from at all. (Note, you wrote `public ExceptionBase<Base>` which doesn't make sense because `ExceptionBase` is not a template).

Comment: @Potatoswatter: A thanks for catching that, I somehow swapped the meaning of `Exception` and `ExceptionBase` somehow in the middle  of writing that. The problem regarding polymorphism is that you can not easily increase the chain an additional level (have some other exception derived from `bad_alloc` and a corresponding one from `OutOfMemoryException`) while still using it Polymorphic (You'd need to make `OutOfMemoryException` a template too, where the type is detemined by the most derived type in the inheritance chain).

Comment: This is very interesting, but I need to test it to ensure I understand the concept properly. In the first two snippets, is `OutOfMemoryException` deriving from a partial specialization of `Exception`?

Comment: @Daniel: There is no specialization involved. `Exception` is a template for which the template parameter determines which exception class it should inherit from. `OutOfMemoryException` inherits from `Exception<std::bad_alloc>` (sorry, I should have explicitely mentioned the actual type), which in turn inherits from std::bad_alloc`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to have your extra exception functionality but without having to create another exception hierarchy. I.e. you can throw standard exceptions with your extra bits:

```
struct MyExceptionInfo { /* your extra functionality goes here */};

template<class T>
struct Ex : T, MyExceptionInfo
{
    template<class A1, class... Args>
    Ex(A1&& a1, Args&&... args)
        : T(std::forward<A1>(a1))
        , MyExceptionInfo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw Ex<std::runtime_error>("oops");
    }
    catch(std::exception &e) {
        if(MyExceptionInfo* my_info = dynamic_cast<MyExceptionInfo*>(&e)) {
            // use MyExceptionInfo here
        }
    }
}
```

You may also like taking a look at [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html) library for inspiration.

Comment: It would probably be better to add a `catch(MyExceptionInfo&)` block above the `catch(std::exception&)` instead of a `dynamic_cast` test :)

Comment: @Drax You would still need the `dynamic_cast` to get the `std::exception` part.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Are `T` and `MyExceptionInfo` private bases for `Ex`? Is there no necessity of public inheritance? BTW, I was looking to `boost::Exception` implementation and it does not inherit from `std::exception`. Maybe my `Exception` class also doesn't need it.

Comment: @Daniel It is public inheritance by default with `struct`, with `class` you would need `: public T, public MyExceptionInfo`. I.e. the inheritance has to be public here.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this solution is pretty, but it might suffice for what you're looking for.
Assume that `std::exception` defines a function called `func1()`. You'll of course get it from both paths in the inheritance and any calls to `OutOfMemoryException::func1()` would give you a compile-time message about ambiguous base class.

So here's the hacky and not-so-pretty solution. Override the non-virtual function from `std::exception` and just forward either version. Either `Exception::func1()` or `std::bad_alloc::func1()`.

I do realize that this is ugly because you're overriding a non-virtual function. You're also faced with the perfect forwarding problem if the overriden function takes parameters. There may be copying of things you don't want to copy if you're not careful, etc. But it should allow you to call the member functions from std::exception.

Comment: The big problem is when I throw an `OutOfMemoryException` and attempt to catch `std::exception`. Since it is an ambiguous base class, the up-casting doesn't work and it goes to `catch(...)` or `std::terminate`.

Comment: I see. That is a problem. Are you not able to have one of the bases not be a base but a member? Then provide whatever functionality is unique to it through wrappers. Of course, in your case, if you want to be able to catch a `OutOfMemoryException` as an `Exception` and as a `std::bad_alloc` as well as a `std::exception`, then this won't work. But if you can pick just one of those along with `std::exception`, then you should be OK.

Comment: There is no real necessity to inherit from `std::exception` in my `Exception` class. It is just for convenience due the unit test framework catching `std::exception`. I guess `OutOfMemoryException` must derive from `std::bad_alloc` since it could broke existing code when I replace it in my `new_handler`