# What is the advantage of using dynamic_cast instead of conventional polymorphism?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

We can use Polymorphism (inheritance + virtual functions) in order to generalize different types under a common base-type, and then refer to different objects as if they were of the same type.

Using `dynamic_cast` appears to be the exact opposite approach, as in essence we are checking the specific type of an object before deciding what action we want to take.

Is there any known example for something that cannot be implemented with conventional polymorphism as easily as it is implemented with `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: Two applications come to mind: Multiple dispatch, and type erasure like `boost::any`.

Comment: Another application is catching exceptions via the base class interface. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214128/custom-exception-hierarchy-dreaded-diamond-from-stdexception-and-stdbad-all/22220133#22220133

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself wanting a member function like "IsConcreteX" in a base class (edit: or, more precisely, a function like "ConcreteX *GetConcreteX"), you are basically implementing your own `dynamic_cast`. For example:

```
class Movie
{
    // ...
    virtual bool IsActionMovie() const = 0; 
};

class ActionMovie : public Movie
{
    // ...
    virtual bool IsActionMovie() const { return true; }
};

class ComedyMovie : public Movie
{
    // ...
    virtual bool IsActionMovie() const { return false; }
};


void f(Movie const &movie)
{
    if (movie.IsActionMovie())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This may look cleaner than a `dynamic_cast`, but on closer inspection, you'll soon realise that you've not gained anything except for the fact that the "evil" `dynamic_cast` no longer appears in your code (provided you're not using an ancient compiler which doesn't implement `dynamic_cast`! :)). It's even worse - the "self-written dynamic cast" approach is verbose, error-prone and repetitve, while `dynamic_cast` will work just fine with no additional code whatsoever in the class definitions.

So the real question should be whether there are situations where it **makes sense that a base class knows about a concrete derived class**. The answer is: usually it doesn't, but you will doubtlessly encounter such situations.

Think, in very abstract terms, about a component of your software which transmits objects from one part (A) to another (B). Those objects are of type `Class1` or `Class2`, with `Class2` *is-a* `Class1`.

```
Class1
  ^
  |
  |
Class2


A - - - - - - - -> B
    (objects)
```

B, however, has some special handling only for `Class2`. B may be a completely different part of the system, written by different people, or legacy code. In this case, you want to reuse the A-to-B communication without any modification, and you may not be in a position to modify B, either. It may therefore make sense to explicitly ask whether you are dealing with `Class1` or `Class2` objects at the other end of the line.

```
void receiveDataInB(Class1 &object)
{
    normalHandlingForClass1AndAnySubclass(object);
    if (typeid(object) == typeid(Class2))
    {
        additionalSpecialHandlingForClass2(dynamic_cast<Class2 &>(object));
    }
}
```

Here is an alternative version which does not use `typeid`:

```
void receiveDataInB(Class1 &object)
{
    normalHandlingForClass1AndAnySubclass(object);
    Class2 *ptr = dynamic_cast<Class2 *>(&object);
    if (ptr != 0)
    {
        additionalSpecialHandlingForClass2(*ptr);
    }
}
```

This might be preferable if `Class2` is not a leaf class (i.e. if there may be classes further deriving from it).

In the end, it often comes down to whether you are designing a whole system with all its parts from the beginning or have to modify or adapt parts of it at a later stage. But if you ever find yourself confronted with a problem like the one above, you may come to appreciate `dynamic_cast` as the right tool for the right job in the right situation.

Comment: I would avoid the `typeid` check.  It will return false if the object has a class type derived from `Class2`, even if somebody just composed it with a mix-in or overrode one virtual function.  The pointer version of `dynamic_cast` would succeed on those cases.

Comment: @aschepler: good points. I'll edit my answer to mention them.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to do things which you can only do to the derived type. But this is usually a hint that a redesign is in order.

```
struct Foo
{
  virtual ~Foo() {}
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
  void bar() const {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo * f = new Bar();
  Bar* b = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(f);
  if (b) b->bar(); 
  delete f;
}
```

Comment: In your example, I could simply declare `bar` in all classes, and implement whatever I want to do for each class (even with an empty function). So I still don't see any advantage in this example.

Comment: @barakmanos But you can't always do that. And `bar()` might make no sense in `Foo`. The only "advantage" is that you cannot call `f->bar();`. This is probably the most common use of `dynamic_cast`, but it is definitely code smell.

Comment: What does come to mind (came to my mind after reading your answer), is that `dynamic_cast` might become handy if I want to `delete` only objects of a certain type (though, even in this case, I could simply add a `DestroyMe` virtual function, that would `delete this` only in some classes and would do nothing in other classes).

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any case where it's not possible to use virtual functions (other than such things as `boost:any` and similar "lost the original type" work).

However, I have found myself using `dynamic_cast` a few times in the Pascal compiler I'm currently writing in C++. Mostly because it's a "better" solution than adding a dozen virtual functions to the baseclass, that are ONLY used in one or two places when you already (should) know what type the object is. Currently, out of roughly 4300 lines of code, there are 6 instances of `dynamic_cast` - one of which can probably be "fixed" by actually storing the type as the derived type rather than the base-type.

In a couple of places, I use things like `ArrayDecl* a = dynamic_cast<ArrayDecl*>(type);` to determine that `type` is indeed an array declaration, and not someone using an non-array type as a base, when accessing an index (and I also need `a` to access the array type information later). Again, adding all the virtual functions to the base `TypeDecl` class would give lots of functions that mostly return nothing useful (e.g. `NULL`), and aren't called except when you already know that the class is (or at least should be) one of the derived types. For example, getting to know the range/size of an array is useless for types that aren't arrays.

Answer (score 1):

No advantages really. Sometimes `dynamic_cast` is useful for a quick hack, but generally it is better to design classes properly and use polymorphism. There may be cases when due to some reasons it is not possible to modify the base class in order to add necessary virtual functions (e.g. it is from a third-party which we do not want to modify), but still `dynamic_cast` usage should be an exception, not a rule.
An often used argument that it is not convenient to add everything to the base class does not work really, since the Visitor pattern (see e.g. http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/2) solves this problem in a more organised way purely with polymorphism - using Visitor you can keep the base class small and still use virtual functions without casting.

Comment: Interesting... How exactly can you keep the base class small and still use virtual functions without casting?

Comment: Read about the visitor pattern and see for yourself - it is possible, though a little bit tricky

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` needs to be used on base class pointer for down cast when member function is not available in base class, but only in derived class. There is no advantage to use it. It is a way to safely down cast when virtual function is not overridden from base class. Check for null pointer on return value. You are correct in that it is used where there is no virtual function derivation.